# How to store a picture within Active Directory using Ruby in a Rail3App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, active-directory, ldap

All I want to do is to upload an image into the Active Directory. So far I can update any AD information but the image. I have tried to search for some idea but came up with nothing so far.

Do I have to encode an image in a certain way? Do I just ldap-replace the jpegPhoto attribute with a byte-string of the photo?

Any hint towards a solution would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, there is an attribute in Active directory called thumbnailPhoto. According to [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292029/en-us) The thumbNailPhoto attribute contains octet string type data. The AD interprets octet string data as an array of bytes.

If you want a sample code in C# you can get [something here](http://lgmorand.developpez.com/dotnet/adimage/).

On the theorical point of view you can also inject a photo with LDIF using tools like "B64" to code your image file in base 64.

**Secondly**, On my point of view a Directory is not a database.
So, even if the attribute exists (created by netscape according to the OID [2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.35](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.35&action=display)), even if Microsoft explain us how to put a picture into Active Directory, I think that it's better to register an URL, or a path to a file from a file system into a Directory.

I have no idea of the impact on performance of AD if I load each entry with 40 Ko (average size of a thumbnail photo). But I know that if there are bad written programs on the network, I mean kind of program that load all the attributes when they search an entry into the directory, this will considerably load the network.

I hope it helps.

JP

Comment: There are 3 attributes to store photo-Data jpegPhoto, Photo and thumbnailPhoto. I got that far, I also leared that photo was originally intended for use back in the facsimile-age, so I intend not to use that. Yes i concur that storing an image into AD might slow down the server... and I also told that to my boss. Sadly, he still wants to see peoples pictures when he browses his outlook-contacts :-(, when I suggested some mini-app that allows storage of pictures and offers them as a service so i'd only need to store the link in AD he said he doesnt want another frontend and another databas. :-(

Comment: Do you try to add an image just like Microsoft explain it and just modify the user form in Exchange server and add the attribute to the form ?

Comment: Well I have a rails application and I talk to AD using the ldap protocol. Every text information i wish to send to AD i force-encode to ASCII-8bit and then just call the according ldap-method like ldap_add, ldap_replace or ldap_delete ... all that works great for Strings and Flag-Registers. I just can't find out how to send a picture to AD via ldap :-( ... and right now its starting to annoy me that whatever I try, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you try to encode a BMP in Base 64 and add the content as string to one of the photo attribute ?

Comment: sadly I still havent figured out how to do it... I lost my job a few weeks later due to a financial crisis in the company. So I haven't anymore had the opportunity to play more with AD. As soon as I can again access an AD I will hopefully remember to test that. Thx so far

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and was able to get it working by creating a File stream and passing it through to `@ldap.replace_attribute` as a binary file. i.e.

```
thumbnail_stream = open("path_to_file")
@ldap.replace_attribute USERS_DN, :thumbnailPhoto, File.binread(thumbnail_stream)
```

Where `@ldap` is an instance of `net/ldap`, *bound* to AD. i.e.

```
@ldap = Net::LDAP.new
@ldap.host = ''
@ldap.port = ''
@ldap.auth USERNAME, PASSWORD
@ldap.bind
```